# trying to concat in the RAISE() function using || results in a syntax error

Tags: database, sqlite

[relevant documentation](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html)

I am trying to create a trigger that catches inserts into the Viewings table where the foreign key (viewings.location) does not correspond to an existing primary key in the Places table (places.location). The logic, from what I can tell, works as expected. However my issue comes from trying to concatenate the attempted value into the error-message in the raise function. Is this not allowed?

```
create trigger catchForeignKeyError BEFORE INSERT ON VIEWINGS
BEGIN
SELECT CASE 
WHEN NEW.location NOT IN (SELECT PLACES.location FROM PLACES) THEN 
RAISE(ABORT, 'Error: Insert into the VIEWINGS table references location '''||NEW.location||''' that is not found in the PLACES table.') 
END; 
END;
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @Mureinik Error: near "||": syntax error

Comment: What is that `'''`?

Comment: @Yunnosch One escaped quote, and the quote for the end of the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the SQLite grammar, the second parameter of the RAISE() expression is not a string but a name:

```
RAISE(ABORT, some_error)
```

Identifiers can be quoted with double quotes, and for historical reasons, SQLite [accepts a string (with single quotes) where an identifier is expected](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html), but then it must be a single string, not a string expression composed of other values:

```
RAISE(ABORT, "some error")
```

There is no mechanism to get a dynamic value into the error message, except by creating a user-defined function for this.

Comment: User-defined functions cannot be created in SQLite itself. (However, any scripting language makes this easy.)